# rack-mini-profiler is showing profiling static files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, profiling, rack, rack-mini-profiler

I'm using rack-mini-profiler after watching it's railscast (http://railscasts.com/episodes/368-miniprofiler).

I added it to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
```

Installed it using bundler and started my dev environment using "rails s".
The profilling works, it shows up at the left upper corner of the web page, but it happens to profile all the static files (js, css, images, etc). It also seems that it has a limit of 10 lines, so the actual request is hidden.

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to configure it so it will avoid profiling static files?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, here's how I have done it:

Used the 0.0.18 version of the gem (which is not on rubygems.org, you'll have to install it from the project's git repo) and created a config file at /config/initializers/miniprofiler.rb:

```
Rack::MiniProfiler.config.skip_paths << "/images/"
Rack::MiniProfiler.config.skip_paths << "/stylesheets/"
Rack::MiniProfiler.config.skip_paths << "/javascripts/"
Rack::MiniProfiler.config.skip_paths << "/favicon.ico"
```

That did the trick

Comment: do you mind updating the doco on github, also we should probably update our railtie for this, can you post a bug on http://community.miniprofiler.com

Comment: I'm having this same issue (5 years later!) and I attempted to correct it with this answer but didn't work.  Also I have installed the following version of mini profiler `rack-mini-profiler-0.10.7`